# Should Form input value can be declare as empty in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a simple form in angular js, On this form submission, I didn't get any input values. Then I had to declare that input model name was empty, it was working. I get the input value. I have doubt for, Should we have to declare the input variable name as empty before the form submission?

Here is my code.

```
var login = angular.module("loginApp",[])
.controller("loginController", function($scope){
    $scope.login = {
        name : "",
        pwd : "",
    }
    $scope.login.submit = function(user){
        //some text here
    }

});
```

Comment: Just disable the submit button when input is empty.

Comment: okay fine. but, I just asked whether we should declare the form variable (name, pwd) as an empty string in our code?

Comment: You can do that as you did. But in such case, we always disable the button with no input.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having to right less. You can pass in your login object right from your view like this:

```
 <body ng-controller="loginCtrl as vm">
  <form name="formLogin" novalidate="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="login.name" />
    <input type="password" ng-model="login.password" />
    <button ng-click="vm.submit(login)">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

And your controller would only need a submit function:

```
 app.controller("loginCtrl",function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.submit = function(login){
      alert("Logging In " + angular.toJson(login));
    }
  })
```

Here's a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/oQwSDt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign something it holds undefined